# python client can't pass keyfile to wrap_socket()

Tags: python, ssl

I have an SSL socket server written in C and hosted on an AWS instance running RHEL.  The Server is using a self signed cert at the moment and im trying to connect with a python client.  When I try to specify the public key to use I get the following error:

```
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'
```

Simplest client code is:

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
import ssl
#Host is the public domain name of an AWS instance
HOST = "some.host.amazonaws.com"
#Create context
con = ssl.create_default_context()
#Wrap socket with ssl context
soc = con.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), keyfile="pubkey.pem", server_hostname = HOST)
#connect to host
soc.connect((HOST, 8615))
#Get and print the host cert
cert = soc.getpeercert()
pprint.pprint(cert)
```

In the python docs it says that I can specify the keyfile/certfile so am confused as to why this is failing.

If I remove `keyfile="pubkey.pem"` then it fails to verify the certificate:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I don't believe it is the server as I have run s_client and get the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
   i:/C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
issuer=/C=AU/ST=Victoria/L=Sydney/O=psd-it/OU=IT/CN=some.host.amazonaws.com/emailAddress=admin@psd-it.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1681 bytes and written 712 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 3D393B247FDA6BCDC933047DCC70FA60BEC8DB0D493DEB86BB15B70C0BD025BF
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 61A6A039398F326940A24165EB803A49DBA7128C4C3EB23C416111B1BF4571B79BE69FBBD755CDB8E81BBB8799FC93EC
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1484711374
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
test
read:errno=0
```

Seems to be the client cert is not being sent to the server.  Is there a way to specify the public key when creating the connection that I am missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'

There is no keyfile argument when calling `context.wrap_socket(...)`. There is a keyfile argument when calling `ssl.wrap_socket(...)`. The reason for this is that the context should be created with a keyfile if needed while `ssl.wrap_socket(...)` creates a new context.

For more details see [documentation of `context.wrap_socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket) vs. [documentation of `ssl.wrap_socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help. I did have to also call `load_verify_locations("/path/to/root/rootCA.pem")` as it failed on `load_default_certs()` even though it is installed in the keychain (macOS) not sure why but its working now! Thanks again :)

Comment: @PSD: Python is not using the keychain from Mac OS X.